# Running system command in java GUI by double click jar file get null result

Tags: java, command, processbuilder

Here is the code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/which", "adb");

    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = processBuilder1.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    inputStreamThread inputTread = new inputStreamThread(process);
    inputTread.run();

    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    process.destroy();

    ADB = inputTread.inputStreamOutput.substring(0,inputTread.inputStreamOutput.length()-1);
```

If I run it with `java -jar xxxx.jar`, I can get the true result, but if i double click jar file, ADB result is null, i try the new `ProcessBuilder("which", "adb");`  but it didn't work.

Comment: osx 10.14  operating system

Comment: what's the different between double-click and command line